# Use of dynamic SQL in a procedure

Tags: plsql, procedure

The problem statement:
Procedure accepts a table name, and one of its column name as values.
I need the all the values of column.

Note: There is no WHERE clause here. We need to use Dynamic SQL here.

Kindly reply with solutions to the above problem.
Do i need to use a BULK COLLECT here...If yes...How?

This is What I tried. Although the procedure gets compiled, it doesn't get executed.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GET_INFO
(
P_TAB VARCHAR2,
P_COL1 VARCHAR2
)
IS
EXEC varchar2(255);
v_tab varchar2(25);
v_col1 varchar2(25);
is
type ename_t is table of emp.ename%type
index by binary_integer;
enam ename_t;
i number:=0;
BEGIN
select table_name into v_tab
from user_tab_cols where
table_name=p_tab;

select column_name into v_col1
from user_tab_cols where
column_name=p_col1;


exec:='select '||v_col1||' from '||v_tab;
execute immediate exec
bulk collect into enam;

for i in enam.first..enam.last
LOOP
dbms_output.put_line(enam(i));
END LOOP;

exception

when no_data_found
then
dbms_output.put_line('Table or Column does not Exist');
end;
```

execute GET_INFO('EMP','ENAME');

Comment: What do you mean by 'it doesn't get executed'?  Does an error occur when you run it?  Do you run it and no output occurs?

Answer (score 1):

The following query will cause a `ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows` error if the table you want to select from from has any more than one column:

```
select table_name into v_tab
 from user_tab_cols where
 table_name=p_tab;
```

This is because this query returns one row for each column in the table, when you only need one row for the table itself.  You're querying the wrong data dictionary view here.  Replace `user_tab_cols` in this query with `user_tables` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
HI I have just modified your query. Please have a look and let me know for any queries.

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GET_INFO(
    P_TAB  VARCHAR2,
    P_COL1 VARCHAR2,
    P_SCHEMA VARCHAR2)
IS
  EXEC   VARCHAR2(255);
  v_tab  VARCHAR2(25);
  v_col1 VARCHAR2(25);
type ename_t
IS
  TABLE OF emp.ename%type INDEX BY binary_integer;
  enam ename_t;
  i NUMBER:=0;
BEGIN
  SELECT table_name INTO v_tab FROM all_tab_cols WHERE table_name=p_tab
  AND OWNER = P_SCHEMA
  AND ROWNUM < 2;
  SELECT column_name INTO v_col1 FROM all_tab_cols WHERE column_name=p_col1
  AND ROWNUM < 2;
  EXEC:='select '||v_col1||' from '||P_SCHEMA||'.'||v_tab;
  EXECUTE immediate EXEC bulk collect INTO enam;
  dbms_output.put_line(EXEC);
  FOR i IN enam.first..enam.last
  LOOP
    dbms_output.put_line(enam(i));
  END LOOP;
EXCEPTION
WHEN no_data_found THEN
  dbms_output.put_line('Table or Column does not Exist');
END;
```

Comment: Thanks for the replies mr.roy and mr.woodward. It is much appreciated.

Comment: What do I Enter in place of schema in the procedure that you have created and how does it make your code different. I hope you understand I am a beginner. Thanks once again